# If I set a new linux copy up, and then set the hostname in /etc/sysconfig/network (CentOS) is that my FQDN?

Tags: linux, centos

Is my full qualified domain name my host name, if I set up a new server and set it in /etc/sysconfig/network?

I have two VM's setup on my LAN, and I noticed that one saw the other as puppet-db.apt15 which I am guessing is my FQDN? Does the apt15 get appended from my router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to change it in /etc/hosts.  Once you've done this, a simple "service network restart" should sort you out.

Yes, your FQDN is your full domain name, complete with the last dotted part(s) (i.e., for a server named "fancypants", while you might refer to it as "fancypants" casually, its FQDN is actually "fancypants.somedomain.net").  Type "hostname" to see what your server thinks it is.